# Difference/Similarity between VBR and EBR

Tags: windows, partition, mbr

What is the difference between Volume Boot Record and Extended Boot Record?
Are they same or different? Do they occupy first 512 bytes of partition/volume?

I have read wiki articles but can't seem to find out if they are one and the same.

Answer (score 1):

**VBR:** On non-partitioned storage devices, the VBR is the first sector of the device. On partitioned devices, VBR is the first sector of a partition.

**EBR:** Describes the subdivision into logical partitions of a single extended partition designated in the Master Boot Record (MBR). The first EBR will always be on the first sector of the extended partition.  Other EBR's, if any, may not be.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have a followup question,  does an extended partition also start with a VBR and then EBR follows it, or VBR does not apply to extended partitions?

Comment: @balajir712 An EBR itself has a formal structure similar to an MBR. However, it is usually zero-filled except for a partition table and boot record signature. This is a good description https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/PartTables2.htm